# Angular-FileUploader 1.x.x - Adding form data to items

Tags: angularjs, http, file-upload, form-data, angular-file-upload

Hi there can't figure out how to add, formdata to my upload request with angular-fileuploader

tried with onBeforeUploadItem, but it dosen't add the data :/

Ctrl

```
   .controller('uplCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, FileUploader) {

        var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
            url: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        });

        uploader.onBeforeUploadItem = function(item) {
            item.formData.push({some: 'data'});
        };
 });
```

At front end i just use the `uploader="uploader" multiple` and `uploader.uploadAll()`

It uploads fine, but just won't add my custom form data

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you.

At angular controller:

```
.controller('uploadCtrl', function ($scope, FileUploader) {
    $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
        url: "./api/file/upload",
        formData: [
            { "data1": "value1" },
            { "data2": "value2" }
        ]
    });
});
```

At server side(In FileController, method: upload):

```
var provider = GetMultipartProvider();
var result = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

var data1 = result.FormData.Get("data1");
var data2 = result.FormData.Get("data2");
```